# AWS cross account access creating issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to launch a RDS instance in VPC and also modify a DB security group using boto. Everything i already did using my root AWS access and secret key, and they are functional.

But the problem is when i tried to do so with [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html)
it suffers from error.

1. During authorize my public ip to RDS security group. i got error like:

   VPC DB Security Groups cannot be modified with this API version.  Please use an API version between 2012-01-15 and 2012-10-31 to modify this group

but i am authorizing a RDS security group not VPC security group

2. During creating RDS instances in VPC i got error like:

   Vpc associated with db subnet group cloudly-test1 does not exist.

but i did created instances with cloudly-test1 subnet group and this obviously exist.

can't find out what is wrong? got any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using an older version of the SDK or you haven't told it to use the newer version of the API. First try upgrading the SDK, then check out [this link](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) might help you with the configuration.